# data-pterror="SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

What is this error and how to fix?

data-pterror="SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Below is what's in the gatsby-ssr.js. It run successfully after run npm start. But when check inspect there is the syntaxError. Please can you check what is causing this error and help me fix it.

[Inspect > elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Wkg.png)

gatsby-ssr.js page

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Partytown } from '@builder.io/partytown/react'


export function onRenderBody({ setHeadComponents, setPreBodyComponents, setHtmlAttributes }) {
    
    setHtmlAttributes({ lang: 'en' })
    setHeadComponents([
        <Partytown key="partytown" debug={true} forward={['dataLayer.push']} />,
        <script
  type="text/partytown"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `        <script>
      function initFreshChat() {
        window.fcWidget.init({
          token: "3456d-e81e-4201-b9ac-324efdvsffda,
          host: "https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com"
        });
      }
      function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
    </script>`
  }}
/>,

    ])
    // Below is Optional for Disabled JS
    setPreBodyComponents([
      

    ])
}
```

Comment: Please leave the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script is not valid. As it is, you are adding a `<script>` inside a `<script>`. Your snippet should look like:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Partytown } from "@builder.io/partytown/react";

export function onRenderBody({
  setHeadComponents,
  setPreBodyComponents,
  setHtmlAttributes,
}) {
  setHtmlAttributes({ lang: "en" });
  setHeadComponents([
    <Partytown key="partytown" debug={true} forward={["dataLayer.push"]} />,
    <script
      type="text/partytown"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `function initFreshChat() {
            window.fcWidget.init({
              token: "3456d-e81e-4201-b9ac-324efdvsffda,
              host: "https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com"
            });
          }
          function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
    `,
      }}
    />,

    ,
  ]);
  // Below is Optional for Disabled JS
  setPreBodyComponents([]);
}
```

Directly adding the script between backticks (`` ` ``) should do the trick.